DBT - Delete rows from a table after a left join
i have a transactional table and a complementary table.
In this incremental transactional model i'm doing a left join to this complementary table so maybe not all the rows in the complementary table exists in the main one.
I need to mark in some way (i already have a flag column to do this) the rows that actually joins and after update some of the columns in the main table with the columns of the complementary table, delete this rows that joined, from the complementary table.
Any ideas on how to do this? Only maybe possible with a macro? I wouldn't like to make another extra join to mark them and then delete the rows; i would like if possible to do this on the main model after the join, maybe with something like:
{% set variable %}
  DELETE FROM complementary table ...
{% endset %}

{% do run_query(variable) %}

Edit:
Current model, something like this
table1
col_1       col_2       col_3       col_4
10          'Hello'     'World'     'Hi'
20          'Hello'     'World'     'Hi'

table2
col_1       col_2       col_3       col_4
10          'Goodbye'   'Earth'     null
30          'Goodbye'   'Earth'     null

model:
SELECT
    tab1.col_1
    ,COALESCE(tab2.col_2,tab1.col_2)
    ,COALESCE(tab2.col_3,tab1.col_3)
    ,tab1.col_4
  FROM
    {{ source('xxx','table1') }} tab1
  LEFT JOIN
    {{ source('xxx','table2') }} tab2
  ON 
    tab1.col_1 = tab2.col_1

Expected result table1
col_1       col_2         col_3       col_4
10          'Goodbye'     'Earth'     'Hi'
20          'Hello'       'World'     'Hi'

Expected result table2
col_1       col_2       col_3       col_4
10          'Goodbye'   'Earth'     1
30          'Goodbye'   'Earth'     null

And then make a delete on table2 where col_4 = 1

Could you just use where not exists to create an anti join?

add an edit above @JoshD.

The way I see the use case, there are 3 different objects: two sources that are not managed by dbt (table 1, table 2) and a model that uses table 1 and table 2.
If that is correct, an option could be:

[optional] Create a stg model on table_2 that tags items present in table_1 (this way source is still not managed by dbt -- e.g. adds a col_4 = 1).
Use a post-hook in your model to delete from the source table_2 (or the stg model) with the conditions you have.

e.g. post hook:
{{  config(
        post_hook = [
        'delete from table_2 where table_2.col_1 in (select col_1 from ' ~ this ~ ')'
/* or, if using the stg 
        'delete from stg_table_2 where col_4 = 1'
    */
        ]
    )
}}

SELECT
    tab1.col_1
    ,COALESCE(tab2.col_2,tab1.col_2)
    ,COALESCE(tab2.col_3,tab1.col_3)
    ,tab1.col_4
  FROM
    {{ source('xxx','table1') }} tab1
  LEFT JOIN
    {{ source('xxx','table2') }} tab2
  ON 
    tab1.col_1 = tab2.col_1

